# Extension method to convert Flags to IEnumerable<Enum> and conversely (C#)

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods, ienumerable

I spent a couple hours trying to figure out a generic way of converting an Enum mask to an array of Enum values and, conversely, an array of Enum values to its Enum mask.

Writing an extension method to do so was a bit of a pain so I just wanted to share my solution in case it could help someone. I'm sure it could be improved but, here it is!

Comment: Why do you want to convert an enum mask to an array of enums? What would you do with it that you can't do with the mask directly?

Comment: And gosh. Its really annoying writing extension methods for enums isn't it? You can do `enums.Aggregate((x,y)=>x|y);` as a really quick way of doing enum values to mask though but its a pain to put it in an extension method due to all the other code you need wrapping it to deal with conversions, etc.

Comment: My database contains masks, but my REST API exposes list of values. So I needed a convenient way to go back and forth. I didn't thought about the aggregate, you have a good point!

Answer (score 11):

The extension method below returns a mask from a list of Enum values.

```
public static T ToMask<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type.");

     int builtValue = 0;
     foreach (T value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
     {
        if (values.Contains(value))
        {
            builtValue |= Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
    }
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), builtValue.ToString());
}
```

The extension method below returns a list of Enum values from a mask.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ToValues<T>(this T flags) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type.");

    int inputInt = (int)(object)(T)flags;
    foreach (T value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
    {
        int valueInt = (int)(object)(T)value;
        if (0 != (valueInt & inputInt))
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that:

1. Generic constraints in c# (`where T : ...`) cannot restrict T to an Enum
2. These methods do not check whether the Enum has the `[Flags]` attribute (could not figure that out)

Usage:

```
[Flags]
public enum TestEnum : int
{
    None = 0,
    Plop = 1,
    Pouet = 2,
    Foo = 4,
    Bar = 8
}
```

To mask:

```
TestEnum[] enums = new[] { TestEnum.None, TestEnum.Plop, TestEnum.Foo };
TestEnum flags = enums.ToMask();

TestEnum expectedFlags = TestEnum.None | TestEnum.Plop | TestEnum.Foo;
Assert.AreEqual(expectedFlags, flags);
```

To values:

```
TestEnum flags = TestEnum.None | TestEnum.Plop | TestEnum.Foo;
TestEnum[] array = flags.ToValues().ToArray();

TestEnum[] expectedArray = new[] { TestEnum.Plop, TestEnum.Foo };
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedArray, array);
```

Comment: Great helper methods, just two additions:
- where T : Enum is possible as of C# 7.3.
- return (T)(object)flags in ToMask() may be a little less awkward (does anyone know why return (T)flags is not working?)

Answer (score 6):

I needed a simple solution for converting the opposite direction (instead of having to include the extension), so here's a Linq solution to turn an IEnumerable of your enum into a flagged enum:

```
MyEnum e = MyEnumList.Aggregate((MyEnum)0, (a,b) => a |= b);
```

Comment: To get the IEnumerable from the flag in a similar in-line fashion:
List<MyEnum> constituentFlags = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>().Where(e => me.HasFlag(e)).ToList();